# xpath not returning nodes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath

I'm working on a chrome addon that parses a web page and displays some data on it. I've been using javascript and navigating the dom but I want to switch to xpath.

I'm trying to use xpaths to get the correct nodes, this works fine for some xpaths, but others return no nodes for some reason (even children of a node that works). I'm copying the xpath out of chromes "Copy Xpath" in the "inspect element" tool so I don't think I'm entering the xpath wrong.

For example:

This works:

```
//*[@id="auctions-sold"]
```

But this does not:

```
//*[@id="auctions-sold"]/div/table
```

my code looks like this:

```
var result = document.evaluate('//*[@id="auctions-sold"]/div/table', document, null, 0, null), item;

while (item = result.iterateNext()) {
    console.log(item)
}
console.log("done loop")
```

Whenever I run the xpath that specifies the table, the item does not get logged and the console has "Done loop"

Whenever I run the xpath that species the "auctions-sold" node the xpath works fine and the console displays the node and says "done loop"

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/W88vs/

Comment: What does the DOM look like?

Comment: See if `'//*[@id="auctions-sold"]/*[local-name()="div"]/*[local-name()="table"]'` works. If it does, it is failing because your HTML document declares an XHTML namespace (look for an `xmlns` attribute).

Comment: yeah helderdarocha's fix worked, the page I'm using is "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" as its xmlns attribute